# svg.js & JsFiddle: Cannot read property 'size' of null on element initialization

Tags: jsfiddle, svg.js

I would like to experiment with svg.js library but I cannot understand what's wrong when I try to play through snippet console...

```js
var draw = SVG('playground').size(200, 200);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.13/svg.js"></script>
<div id='playground'></div>
```

... or [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/buonstefano/2vzom03w/7/)

Comment: use `var draw = SVG().addTo('#playground').size(200, 200);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing Fuzzyma's response above...

You are missing the CSS selector for the element, it should be:

```
var draw = SVG().addTo('#playground').size(200, 200);
```

Hopefully that helps!